# boxplot won't display with ggvis

Tags: r, plot, ggvis

I'm trying to make a boxplot with `ggvis` and I can't seem to view one even with a simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny) #I think this is required? not sure
data.frame(theVar = c(1,5:10,15)) %>% ggvis(x = ~theVar) #makes a histogram

data.frame(theVar = c(1,5:10,15)) %>% ggvis(x = ~theVar) %>% layer_boxplots()

Error: Can't find prop y.update
```

forcing a y variable:

```
data.frame(theVar = c(1,5:10,15)) %>% ggvis(x = ~theVar,y=~theVar) %>% layer_boxplots()
```

seems to turn it into intervals? not sure what its doing but it's not a boxplot, nor should a boxplot need an X and Y...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single variable, you have to use your variable for `y` and specify a dummy for `x`:

```
library(ggvis)
data.frame(theVar = c(1,5:10,15)) %>% ggvis(y = ~theVar, x = ~ 1) %>% layer_boxplots()
```

Comment: ohh I tried y~1 but not x~1
thanks!
seems strange that this isn't handled by default when there's only one...

Comment: Any one knows how to add two small vertical lines on the tails of the boxplot?

Comment: This is very useful; for completeness it could be  useful to hide the `x` axis.