# How to select multiple variables on the horizontal axis with ggvis for histograms?

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm just trying to illustrate Central Limit Theorem by taking the mean of random samples of different prob. distributions. I have the following code, in which I increase the sample size of an exponential distribution.

```
set.seed(12577) # for reproducability
n <- 50 
lambda <- 0.2  
out <-  rexp(5000, lambda)
for(i in seq_along(sample_size)) {
  out <- cbind(out, c(replicate(sample_size[i], mean(rexp(n, lambda))) , rep(NA, 5000 - sample_size[i] )))
}
out <- as.data.frame(out)
names(out) <- c("EXP_SAMPLE_5000", paste0("RND_SAMPLE_", sample_size))
```

I would like to use ggvis, to selecting different columns to create histograms. I'm trying the following but is not working:

```
out %>%  ggvis(x = input_select(label = "Choose what to plot:",
                                choices = names(out),
                                selected = "EXP_SAMPLE_5000",
                                map = as.name)) %>% layer_histograms()
```

UPDATE: Following the comments of @Martin Schmelzer, I added the dummy but now the histogram doesn't make sense.

```
out %>%  ggvis(x = ~ 100, y = input_select(label = "Choose what to plot:",
                                choices = names(out),
                                #multiple=TRUE,
                                map = as.name)) %>% layer_histograms()
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28457373/1777111

Comment: I see, I added the dummy, now is plotting but still, but the histograms don't make any sense...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102711/2461552) may be useful.